# React output doesn't change immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have two results (result 1 and result 2). I am adding `result1 = num1+num2` and adding `result2 = result1 + num3 + num4`. All values are changed dynamically. The problem here is that when I change the value of `num1` or `num2`, `result1` is changed but it doesn't change immediately on `result2`. If we change again then it takes the first value.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {  OverlayTrigger, Popover, Radio, Checkbox, Button,InputGroup,Grid,Form,Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Test extends React.Component {

    state = {
        num1: 2,
        num2: 2,

        num3:4,
        num4:4,
        result: 4,
        result2:12
      };

      componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        // only update chart if the data has changed
        if (prevProps.result !== this.props.result2) {
          console.log("Updated ");

          this.setState (prevState =>({
            result: this.props.result

          }));
        }
      }

      handlenum1Change = evt => {
        const value = Number(evt.target.value);

        this.setState(prevState => ({

          num1: value,
          result: prevState.num2 + value,
          result2:prevState.num3+ prevState.num4+prevState.result
        }));
      };
      handlenum2Change = evt => {

        const value = Number(evt.target.value);

        this.setState(prevState => ({

          num2: value,

          result: prevState.num1 + value,
          result2:prevState.num3+ prevState.num4+prevState.result

        }));
      };


      handlenum3Change = evt => {
        const value = Number(evt.target.value);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          num3: value,
          result2: prevState.num4 + value  +prevState.result
        }));
      };
      handlenum4Change = evt => {
        const value = Number(evt.target.value);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          num4: value,
          result2: prevState.num3 + value +prevState.result
        }));
      };


      render() {

        return (
          <Grid>
          <form>
            <label>
              num1
              <input
                type="number"
                name="num1"
                value={this.state.num1}
                onChange={this.handlenum1Change}
              />


              <br/>
              num2
              <input
                type="number"
                name="num2"
                value={this.state.num2}
                onChange={this.handlenum2Change}
              /><br/>
              Result 
              <input type="number" 
              value={this.state.result} 
              readOnly              /><br/>
            </label>

            <br/>
            <label>
              num3
              <input
                type="number"
                name="num3"
                value={this.state.num3}
                onChange={this.handlenum3Change}
              /><br/>
              num4
              <input
                type="number"
                name="num4"
                value={this.state.num4}
                onChange={this.handlenum4Change}
              /><br/>
              Result 2
              <input type="number" value={this.state.result2} readOnly /><br/>
            </label>
          </form>
          </Grid>

        );
      }
    }

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calculating your new results correctly, when you calculate `result2` you're using `prevState.result` instead of the new `result` you just calculated, e.g.:

```
  handlenum1Change = evt => {
    const value = Number(evt.target.value);

    this.setState(prevState => ({

      num1: value,
      result: prevState.num2 + value,
      // this doesn't factor in your new `num1` value at all; it's equivalent to:
      // result2: prevState.num3 + prevState.num4 + prevState.num2 + prevState.num1
      result2: prevState.num3 + prevState.num4 + prevState.result
      // should be:
      // result2: prevState.num3 + prevState.num4 + prevState.num2 + value
    }));
  };
```

(Actually, that's even less clear, as your existing code sets `result2` to the sum of all four previous values, which doesn't match what you say you're trying to do in your question.)

---

But beyond that, why store your results in the store at all? Given you can easily derive them from the current state, why not just do that as you render?

```
handlenum1Change = evt => {
  const value = Number(evt.target.value);
  this.setState({ num1: value });
};

render() {
  const result = this.state.num1 + this.state.num2;
  const result2 = this.state.num1 + this.state.num3 + this.state.num4;

  // then use the `result` and `result2` in your render method instead
  // `this.state.result` and `this.state.result2`
}
```

Only tracking the minimal state that a component needs help to prevent these sorts of errors, as you're only ever updating one thing at a time and letting the change flow through naturally, rather than having to the value and both results. As you see here, that puts extra burden on you as a developer to ensure all those updates are done correctly, and (even in a fairly simple example like this), making a mistake can result in a lot of wasted time while you try and pick out the error.

Comment: Dam such a silly mistake :(. I am still learning. Thank your for the great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can watch for change in  state (just the result part) in componentDidUpdate and update the result2 accordingly. Need not set result2 in handler functions.

Example

```
      componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // only update chart if the data has changed
    if (prevState.result !== this.state.result) {
      console.log("Updated ");

      this.setState (prevState =>({
        result2:this.state.num3+ this.state.num4+this.state.result
      }));
    }
  }
```

[Repl Link](https://repl.it/repls/AttractiveElectronicFiletype)

Answer (score 1):

When doing setState if you use a state that you are updating in the same call, then it doesn't reflect correctly. You need to write it like

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    const result = prevState.num2 + value;
    return {

          num1: value,
          result,
          result2:prevState.num3+ prevState.num4+ result
    }
});
```